# Remove margin from last-of-type but not if only-child

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I want a margin on every row that I am using in Twitter Bootstrap, except if it's `:last-of-type/:last-child` but if it's the `:only-child`, I still want the margin. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Using the answer given, I did the following SASS:

```
.container .row {
  margin-bottom: 15px;

  &:last-child:not(:only-child) {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all note that CSS pseudo-classes such as `:last-of-type/:last-child` look through the **children tree** of the parent to match the desired child element, not through a list of classes. So, `.row:last-of-type` may or may not match the last row.

However if `.row`s are nested by a specific wrapper like `.container`, the following should work:

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/biwowu/1/edit?html,css,output)**.

```css
.container > :last-child:not(:only-child)
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery solution

```
var rowsNum = $('.your-rows').length;

if (rowsNum > 1) {
    $('.your-rows').not(':last-child').css({'margin':'your margin'});
} else {
    $('.your-rows').css({'margin':'your margin'});
}
```

Comment: There's no JQuery tag.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I think of is selecting the row only when there are more than two children.

Select the last rows only from the second row onwards:

```css
.row:nth-child(n+2):last-child
```

### Example

```css
.container {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.container > .row:nth-child(n+2):last-child {
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">No color for only row</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">Color</div>
  <div class="row">Color</div>
  <div class="row">Color</div>
  <div class="row">Color</div>
</div>
```